# Field calculator expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to reclassify my vector layer but I seem to have a mistake in my Code Block. The following is an example of what i want;

Old  values:

- 10000
- 20000, 163000
- 230000 t/m 270000, 30000, 290000

New values:

- 10000
- 20000
- 30000

The code I have in my Code block is the following;

```
    def Reclass( Indexvalue ):
  if (Indexvalue == 10000):
    return 10000
  elif (Indexvalue == 20000) or (Indexvalue==163000 ):
    return 20000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 230000 and Indexvalue <= 270000) or (Indexvalue == 30000) or (Indexvalue == 290000):
    return 30000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 40000 and Indexvalue <= 44000 ):
    return 40000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 50000 and Indexvalue <= 73000 ):
    return 50000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 80000 and Indexvalue <= 97000 ):
    return 60000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 110000 and Indexvalue <= 115000) or (Indexvalue>= 130000 and Indexvalue <= 140000 ):
    return 70000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 150000 and Indexvalue <= 161000) or (Indexvalue ==220000) or (Indexvalue == 221000) or (Indexvalue>= 170000 and Indexvalue <= 194000 ):
    return 80000
  elif (Indexvalue>= 200000 and Indexvalue <= 202000) or (Indexvalue == 280000):
    return 90000
  elif (Indexvalue== 210000):
    return 100000
```

I found this code in a similar question like I had, but it does not work with me. Both VB and Python expressions give a syntax error so I think that the def and the if functions are not properly used by me.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your code seems to have indentation issues (the last 3 `elif` are not at the same level than the previous 3, which in turn are not at the same level than the first 3). Is your code _exactly_ the same than what you posted?

Comment: Syntax error -- Equivalence is "==" not "=".

Comment: The if's are in the code all on the same level, My apologies for the mistake in the question. I replaced all the "=" with "==" and I still have a syntax error.

Comment: Your first line should read `def Reclass (Index):` (without the exclamation marks). You use `!Index!` when you call the function, not when you define it.

Answer (score 6):

the code block should not contain field name but only variable names.

change !Index!  into Index in your code block, but call your function with the field name

define function in code block (any name for your variable). Furthermore, you are testing equality with a single **=** when you should use 2 **==**. This should also be changed in your codeblock. Finally, Python is a case sensitive language, so you must use **or** instead of **OR**

```
def Reclass( Indexvalue ):
  if (Indexvalue == 10000):
    return 10000
  elif (Indexvalue == 20000) or (Indexvalue == 163000 ):
    return 20000
  elif ((Indexvalue>= 230000) and (Indexvalue <= 270000)) or (Indexvalue == 30000) or (Indexvalue == 290000):
    return 30000
```

Use function

```
Reclass(!Index!)
```

As a remark, it is easier to find your mistake if you just start typing the first lines and then add into complexity. If you correct all but one error, you will still get an error message.

Comment: @macroZED thanks, I made a copy-paste and forgot to update the line

Comment: So I did all of the above and I get a different error;

Comment: Nevermind I discovered a Typo. Thank you it worked!

Comment: also check parentheses (see my edit on third line), I've tested it on my side and it runs.

Comment: The code now works fine untill the fifth return. The first 4 returns work perfect, but after that eveything is assigned to 50000. I don't know why.

Comment: probably missing parentheses. Please upate your question with the new code that you are using, but I am sure that you can find the error if you proceed step by step. also you could try to rewrite your code in order to avoid double tests ( use only <= after the first == lines) except if you want "no data" for, e.g.  74000